# Printing a random number on Thonny (Python)

Tags: python-3.x

I have just started to program so my question may sound dump ... I am trying to make the computer choose a random number and print it but it doesn't work here my program ...

```
import random
x = random.int  <--I thought it was like this ...
print(x)
```

Comment: You might want to check the documentation on `random`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try (from 0.0 to 1.0):

```
import random
random.random()
```

or for numbers from 0 to 9:

```
import random
random.randint(0,9)
```

more info: https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html

Comment: ah ok I just tried it worked thanks a lot and sorry for disturbing^^'